# Text to speech from a non-activity simple class

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm trying to call text to speech from a simple class that I'm doing Image operations in it
and since the text to speech TextToSpeech needs context as an argument I can not pass this to it

is there any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You could for example pass a valid `Context` to your simple class in its constructor and then you can use TTS from the simple class:

```
public class MySimpleClass implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private boolean ttsOk;

  // The constructor will create a TextToSpeech instance.
  MySimpleClass(Context context) {
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
  }

  @Override
  // OnInitListener method to receive the TTS engine status
  public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
      ttsOk = true;
    }
    else {
      ttsOk = false;
    }
  }

  // A method to speak something
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // Support older API levels too.
  public void speak(String text, Boolean override) {
    if (ttsOk) {
      if (override) {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);    
      }    
      else {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);    
      }
    }
  }

  // Other code goes here...

}
```

And depending on the exact application design the `Context` could be an `Activity` or the application context. The later one should be used if the life cycle of the class receiving the context reference exceeds that of the class providing it. For example an `Activity` might be destroyed while the class having the reference to it still exists. That would affect the garbage collection and leak memory.

Another option would be to keep all TTS code in the `Activity` which is shown when the "simple class" code is used, pass the "simple class" a reference to the `Activity` and have a public method in the `Activity` to receive text that needs to be spoken:

```
public class MySimpleClass {

  private MyActivity myActivity;

  // The constructor receives a reference to the Activity.
  MySimpleClass(MyActivity activity) {
    myActivity = activity;
  }

  // Other code goes here...

  myActivity.speak("Hello, Stackoverflow!");

}
```

And again when passing a reference to an `Activity` like that one should consider the life cycles of the classes and avoid having the reference in a class that can still exist after the `Activity` is destroyed.

Yet another option would be to have a separate class just for the TTS code. It would take a `Context` as a constructor parameter and provide a method to speak any given text. There's a simple example in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936077/googles-text-to-speech-api-from-android-app/32936643#32936643).

Comment: Not a very good solution for my case to mess with the class constructor
Still I have a solution in mind and I do not know if it will work or not can I create a static method inside a class that I will call speechClass that extends Activity and call the speechClass from my class ?

Comment: Of course instead of using the constructor you can have a separate `setContext(Context ctx)` method in your class and receive it that way. If you mean that you would just make your class extend `Activity` and instantiate it with `speechClass = new SpeechClass()` then I'd say that it won't work. The context will be `null`. It would have to be a "real `Activity`" that's actually constructed by the Android system and shown on the UI. A `Service` also has access to a `Context` so you could have  a `SpeechClass` service if you want to get the context by extending a class. Maybe an overkill...