# How to text to speech and highlight that text

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I want to make an app that speaks while it highlights text (like karaoke songs).

Comment: Here's a [simple text-to-speech example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936077/googles-text-to-speech-api-from-android-app/32936643#32936643). A "custom voice" is a separate issue then and either easy, difficult or practically impossible depending on what you mean by a "custom voice". You might find some help from [older discussions about highlighting text](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+highlight+text) for the highlighting part.

Comment: i want to make an app like this video..........

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qE3egNettY

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm) you have an additional resource you maybe will need:

I think you are looking for a `Text to Speech` functionality.

Just try this (you must adapt this to your particular case):

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
if (txtText.getText().toString().length() == 0){
      tts.speak("You", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      /*Change size or color of "You" in your TextView for e.g.*/
      tts.speak("haven't", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      /*Change size or color of "haven't" in your TextView for e.g.*/
      tts.speak("typed", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      /*Change size or color of "typed" in your TextView for e.g.*/
} else
        tts.speak(txtText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
```

You could change your TextView color with `setSpan()` method.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

1. Start speaking first word.

   `mTts.speak("first word", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`
2. Highlight first word.

   `String first = "This word is "; 
    String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>red</font>"; 
   t.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));`

Or Use `Spannable` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221990/1770868)

3. Detect first word has finished.

   `public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) { 
       //Next word start 
   }`

Comment: `UtteranceProgressListener` does not have the method `onUtteranceCompleted`, where is it?