# Text To Speech without textfield and button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

So, I want to create a text to speech without the use of textfield and button in Android Studio. For example when I open the app it will say "WELCOME TO MY APP" without text field or any button. How can I do that? Need your help.

Comment: Rather than providing it with a string from a text field just pass it a string, and then call the text to speech method in your onViewCreated()

Comment: Take a look at my answer for a TTS Service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43262996/2597775

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextToSpeech t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
            }
        });


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                t1.speak("welcome to my app", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }, 100);


    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (t1 != null) {
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

codes are self explanatory and I tested it with successful result.

Comment: I think it's better to put the speak() code inside the onInit() method after/with setLanguage.  You can't just assume that the engine is going to take 100 ms to initialize.  You don't know what speech engine the user has on their device, and sometimes the Google engine takes up to 6000 ms... so you might as well wait until exactly when it's actually initialized before speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your onCreate():

```
myTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    // replace this Locale with whatever you want                    
                    Locale localeToUse = new Locale("en","US");
                    myTTS.setLanguage(localeToUse);
                    myTTS.speak("Hi, Welcome to my app!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi sir. Just wanna ask if the codes you've given me is for Android Studio? Thanks.