# word to speech on click ( without having to click on any button)

Tags: android, text-to-speech, vocabulary

I'm new to StackOverflow and I need help.
I am developing a new vocabulary app for beginners. I want my app users to be able to hear the pronunciation of any word from the list of vocabulary in my app without needing to click any button ( just clicking the word launches the pronunciation system ).
I've seen many apps in the play store that give this feature but I really can't find out how I can add it to my app.
clarification: in simple words, I have a list of vocab in my app; so I want the app to automatically read/pronounce the word/sentence right after clicking on the word/sentence itself without any button to do so.
thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow at first..!! As far as I understood your issue you need a TTS  (Text-to-Speech) library to be implemented into your project. And when the user taps on the speaker button then pass the string value to tts and it will spell it out. I guess these links will help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_text_to_speech.htm            https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

Comment: hello sir, thank u so much for taking your time into this.
if i get your point well, i think i will need a button that i have to click in order to listen to the pronnunciation, right?
i actually hyave a page in my app with a button and an editText: when i click the button the app reads what i wrote in the box ....
what i actually need is: the ability to read the word/sentence without clicking any speaker button.

Comment: Glad to help upvote if my comment helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133256/text-to-speech-without-textfield-and-button-in-android-studio

Comment: It might help if you get your app to a point where you are satisfied with the UI and layout, where all it needs is to add the feature you're looking for, then post at layout and your code in your question.  As it is now, the question is too general and there is no starting point to work from.

Comment: thank you so much i will absolutely follow ur advice then post a new question later iwth the code and the xml . i really want to upvote your answer but i don't know how to? can u plz show me where i can upvote vuz i'm new here